# How to get elements' value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've the follow code for get the value fot two input and send it to a Ajax file for proccess it. It doesn't work and I put an alert for see what's wrong and the alert return me [object HTMLInputElement].

```
<tr>
    <td>Introduzca licencia: </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="lic" name="lic" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Introduzca apellidos: </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ape" name="ape" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lic=document.getElementById("lic").value;
    var ape=document.getElementById("ape").value;                      
</script>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="load(lic, ape);"/></td>
</tr>
```

If I try that it return the value of the input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function prueba(){
        var lic=document.getElementById("lic").value;
        var ape=document.getElementById("ape").value;
        alert("La licencia es: "+lic+" y los apellidos son: "+ape);
   }
</script>
<tr>
   <td><input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="prueba();"/></td>
```

I don't know why the first code doesn't work if I'm making the variables of the same way.

Comment: `getElementById returns [object HTMLInputElement]` thats true..

Comment: I don't think that this is your real code.

Comment: I put here the relevant code. The rest of the code doesn't affect that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onclick handler (`load(lic, ape);`) for `<input type'='button'>` in the first code block, neither the `load` function nor the two arguments (`lic` and `ape`) are defined.

Change it to:

> `onclick="load();"`

and make your script file as:

```
function load(){
    var lic = document.getElementById("lic").value,
        ape = document.getElementById("ape").value; 

    alert("lic is " + lic); // test
    alert("ape is " + ape); // test
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/dQVGx/)**

P.S. You are missing `<table>` tags. And `document.getElementById` will always return a DOM object.

Comment: Thank you. I put the var in the external file and it works. :)